# Updating a table based on condition

Tags: sql-server-2008, update

I have a database having a staging_table.
From this table, entries are added to other table named Profile.
Whenever staging_table is updated, it checks whether all its entries are present in Profile, if any is not present, add it to profile.
Till, here its fine.
Now I want that even if an entry exists in Profile, there might be a condition where some fields in Profile have been changed. So also want those entries to get updated.

**Requirement: I cannot use any flags or any other table to check for its update.**

Should I compare all fields? But that is very in-efficient.
Please tell me, what should be the most efficient method that I should follow to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: hi there , i think you should try it with merge. for more information take a look here http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-server-2008-t-sql-merge-statement-example.aspx

Comment: @BenediktSchackenberg 
Thanks for the reply.
I have 15 fields in Profile Table & 25 fields in Staging Table.
Any of the field may get change in the process, so , do I need to compare all fields in the ON Clause of the MERGE statement?

Comment: @Raj Wadhwa hi , without more information it is very difficult to say :(

Comment: Ok. Let me explain the scenario.
I have a field BPNumber and Address in the table Profile.
These two field also exists in Staging table.
Data from the staging table is entered in the Profile table whenever BPNumber doesn't exists in Profile table but it is present in Staging Table.
However, If it exists, and If Address is different from profile table, then profile table entry needs to be updated.
This is the scenario.
Like Address, I have 14 Columns. So, Shall I put each in ON clause.
Thanks.

Comment: In that case, it is like DELETE the record and re-insert it.
Not so efficient I guess.

Comment: Before you do any delete, check the effect on tables related to the profile table.

Comment: @EmmadKareem
That is what I am asking. Is there any efficient way to do that?
Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make an efficient compare of all columns between 2 tables, you could use a UNION method with GROUP BY as described in [Diff2Tables](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2004/11/10/2737.aspx). Alternatively, if your profile table can have rows deleted from it without cascade delete, you could, drop indexes that are not for PK of the profile, Delete rows having the same key in both tables, and insert the rows from the other table into the profile then re-build the indexes on the profile table again. This may sound bad but in fact it is not that bad. This is a typical scenario in Data Warehousing.